# Wait for the subshell in Bash IO redirection

Tags: bash, pipe, wait, pid, subshell

The scenario is that I need my main command to run in current shell, this is required or losing all environment stuff, etc.

So, I can't just run my pipe this way:

```
#command-line 1
mainCommand | (
  ...subshell commands...
) &

#this wait works, but main command is in child process
wait $!
```

I have to run main command in current shell:

```
#command-line 2
mainCommand &> >(
  ...subshell commands...
) &

#this wait is waiting for mainCommand, not subshell
wait $!
```

However, in the command line 2, it's just a single command and I can't just send it to background, only the subshell should go to background then I can get its PID.

How to let

- The main command be in current shell
- And the 'wait' command does actually wait for the subshell?

I have the lock file solution but I prefer not using file as the whole script runs continuously and writing/modifying a file again and again is like penetrating the file system.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe `mainCommand` will run for a long time *after* the subshell? Once the subshell exits, `mainCommand` will exit as soon as it tries to write to the now-closed pipe.

Comment: In `bash` 5, you will be able to wait on the process substitution; `mainCommand > >(...); wait` will do what you want.

Comment: yeah, much awaited bash 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of `bash` allow waiting on a process substitution, but until then, I would recommend simply using a named pipe.

```
mkfifo p
( ... subshell commands ... ) < p &
mainCommand > p
wait
```

Comment: tks, i also found a similar solution using RAM file in `/tmp` dir, or `mount -t tmpfs` my own directory; it's similar when `mkfifo` makes a file in `/tmp`

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you put the named pipe; it's just a file-system interface to an in-memory buffer. Nothing actually gets written to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this. you need to add a `kill` in the subshell commands.

```
sleep 100 &
export BACKGROUNDPID=$!

mainCommand &> >(
  ...subshell commands...
  kill "${BACKGROUNDPID}"
) &

wait ${BACKGROUNDPID}"

# execution continue here ...
```

Comment: @datdinhquoc enhanced version

Comment: sleep 100? i dont get it

Comment: That puts a 100-second time limit on how long you'll wait. If the subshell commands are still running after `sleep 100` exits, the script will move on.

Comment: You can use a much greater value that `100`: the idea is that it should still be running in the background when the subshell commands will terminate. The additional `kill` will end the background `sleep` process, and unblock the `wait`